# Multithreading freezes unity editor

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, mono

I outsourced my terrain generation into threads. The threads don't use any unity api stuff and all variables which the thread and the main thread have access to are thread safed via a lock.

My problem is that after a few seconds (sometime 3-4s and sometimes 30s or 40s) the unity editor freezes. If I open up the task manager the cpu and memory percentages are still changing (cpu is about 40-50% and memory about 300mb).

I've already tried unmanged threads and managed thread with the C# ThreadPool. The communication with the main thread goes over a status variable (which is locked) so if the task has finished the main thread collects the data and creates a mesh (every update the main thread checks for the status of the thread).

I've tried it on windows 10 with Unity 5.3/5.4 and on mac os x with unity 5.3/5.4.

Here's the shortened code:

```
public enum SurfaceCalculationStatus{
    NewJob,
    Processing,
    DataReady,
    Ready,
    Aborted
}

public class SurfaceCalculation {
 private SurfaceCalculationStatus scs;

 private object locker = new object();

 public SurfaceCalculation(){
     Debug.Log ("Start Thread");
     //Some inits
     scs = SurfaceCalculationStatus.Ready;

     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => { ThreadFunction();});
 }

 public void Init(int x, int z, int size, int gridSize, SurfaceRenderType srt, Chunk c){
     //Some inits
     lock (locker)
     {
         scs = SurfaceCalculationStatus.NewJob;
     }
 }

 private void ThreadFunction()
 {
     while (true) { 
         if(scs == SurfaceCalculationStatus.Aborted)
         {
             return;
         }
         if (scs == SurfaceCalculationStatus.NewJob) {
             lock (locker)
             {
                 scs = SurfaceCalculationStatus.Processing;

                 //Heavy calculations

                 scs = SurfaceCalculationStatus.DataReady;
             }
         }

         Thread.Sleep (10);
     }
 }

 public void AbortThread(){
     lock (locker)
     {
         scs = SurfaceCalculationStatus.Aborted;
     }
 }
 //Is called by the main thread after all data for the meshes are read
 public void SetReady(){
     lock (locker)
     {
         scs = SurfaceCalculationStatus.Ready;
     }
 }

 //Data from last calculation has been read so thread is ready for next calculation
 public bool IsReady(){
     bool buffer;
     lock (locker)
     {
         buffer = scs == SurfaceCalculationStatus.Ready;
     }
     return buffer;
 }

 //Is data ready to read and create mesh in main thread?
 public bool IsData(){
     bool buffer;
     lock (locker)
     {
         buffer = scs == SurfaceCalculationStatus.DataReady;
     }
     return buffer;
 }
```

}

Comment: I am not an expert, but just guessing a few things you can try. ThreadFunction has a huge lock region and a short thread sleep time. This might occupy the processor more than required. Try to break down into smaller lock region and increase the thread sleep time to 1000 ms or so. First increase this time and see if the performance improves, then you can try breaking down the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate every hint/help because I have no clue why this is happening.
I tried it with a Thread Sleep 1000/2000 and locked only the access on the scs variable which is "shared" between the thread and the main thread. Same result, after a few seconds the editor freezes...